# How to run LDAP delete entry tool in linux using ANT task

Tags: linux, ant, ldap

In linux, I am able to run ldapdelete like this

```
sudo ldapdelete -x -w 1234 -D "cn=Manager,o=project1" -r "o=project1"
```

now I want to do this using ANT task:

```
<target name="ldap-delete">
         <exec executable="ldapdelete" failonerror="false">
           <arg value="-x"/>
           <arg value="-w"/>
           <arg value="${ldap.password}"/>
           <arg value="-D"/>
           <arg value="&quot;${ldap.rootdn}&quot;"/>
           <arg value="-r"/>
           <arg value="&quot;${ldap.entry}&quot;"/>
         </exec>
</target>
```

but it failed when running ANT:

```
[exec] ldap_bind: Invalid DN syntax (34)
[exec]     additional info: invalid DN
[exec] Result: 1
```

what is wrong with my ANT task script?

Thanks

according to martin clayton's comment, I removed quotes around the -D and -r arg values like this:

```
<arg value="-D"/>
<arg value="${ldap.rootdn}"/>
<arg value="-r"/>
<arg value="${ldap.entry}"/>
```

and run ant with verbose mode, I got the following error:

```
 [echo] ldapdelete...
 [exec] Current OS is Linux
 [exec] Executing 'ldapdelete' with arguments:
 [exec] '-x'
 [exec] '-w'
 [exec] '1234'
 [exec] '-D'
 [exec] 'cn=Manager,o=project1'
 [exec] '-r'
 [exec] 'o=project1'
 [exec]
 [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [exec] not part of the command.
 [exec] ldap_search: No such object (32)
 [exec] ldap_delete: No such object (32)
 [exec] Result: 32
```

Comment: You likely don't need the extra quotes you have put around the -D and -r arg values.  Try running Ant in verbose mode (-v) and you'll be able to see the actual ldapdelete command line being run.

Comment: thanks martin. I have updated the question after taking some changes according to your suggestion, still not working.

Comment: `ldapdelete` itself has a verbose mode. Add `<arg value="-v"/>` under `<exec>` to see if `ldapdelete` outputs some useful extra info.

Comment: thanks Chad Nouis, I tried according to your comments, seems that way not working, no detail info showing. I have to use "ant -v" to get more info.

Answer (score 1):

ended up with a solution myself:

```
<target name="ldap-delete">
     <exec executable="ldapdelete" failonerror="false">
       <arg line="-x -w ${ldap.password} -D &quot;${ldap.rootdn}&quot; -r &quot;${ldap.entry}&quot;"/>
     </exec>
</target>
```